# replacing specified columns in one dataframe in pandas/python with another column

Tags: python

I have an excel file that has about 800,000 rows of information with several columns. Some of the column information will change and I have to update it in the original database/excel file. The second database/excel file has identifying information that goes corresponds with the first database (and it will have the newly updated information). The second database/excel file does not have as many rows or columns of information as the first database (because it only gives the information which has changed). My goal is to identify the information that has changed and then update the original database/excel file with the updated information from the second file. I have struggled with this:

```
 if inventory['marker'].equals(inventory2['marker']):
       inventory['retail'] = inventory.replace(inventory['retail'], inventory2['retail'])
```

the original inventory file has 800,000 rows of information and several columns. The inventory2 file is the dataset that has the newly changed information. The marker characteristic is what is used to link the two databases (I can tell what has changed by marker). For some reason, this line of code is not changing the information in the original database (inventory). So, IF the marker matches from both databases (that means the information has changed because the second database only contains the marker items which have changed), then I'd like to replace the original inventory price information with inventory2 price information. (The price information is usually what has been changed.) It still would keep all of the other columns of information intact in the original database (inventory), and I can export it and have a new file with the updated information in the original database (inventory file).

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it does what you need:

```
import pandas as pd

inventory1 = pd.DataFrame({'marker':['aa','bb','cc','dd'], 'col1': [5, 6, 3, 8], 'col2': [1,3,5,9]})
inventory2 = pd.DataFrame({'marker':['bb','dd'], 'col1': [ 243, 844], 'col2': [335,9333]})

for idx, row in inventory2.iterrows():
    inventory1.loc[inventory1['marker'] == row['marker']] = row.values


print (inventory1)
```

#### OUTPUT

```
  marker  col1  col2
0     aa     5     1
1     bb   243   335
2     cc     3     5
3     dd   844  9333
```

Comment: The line of code that you gave me has not seemed to work. The following error message was returned ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 16: given 3

Comment: I tested with data frames that have the same structure. What is the shape of your data frames, how many columns in each? Also do you need to overwrite only one column with the price?

Comment: If the value you need to update is in one column `inventory['retail']`, you can write: 
 inventory1.loc[inventory1['marker'] == row['marker'], 'retail'] = row['retail']

Comment: Thank you for your help as your code has worked; you are appreciated